# How can I convert a HTML link to a HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, jsp

I want to convert this HTML link:

```
<a href="UserServlet?action=listLog&firstName=<c:out value="${user.name}"/>"> Shiko Loget </a>
```

to a HTML form, like:

```
<form name="frmUserPanel" action="UserServlet" method="GET" action="listLog" >
    <input type="submit" value="Logs" value=<%=user %>>
</form>
```

I don't know if this is possible but if anyone has any idea it will help me very much!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside the form add:

```
<input name="action" type="hidden" value="listLog" />
<input name="firstName" type="hidden" value="${user.name}" />
```

Remove the second action attribute in your current form tag

Comment: How can I do that? I am new here :) I said only that this was helpful!